# How to call cobol program from assembly (z/os IBM)

Tags: assembly, mainframe

How to call a COBOL program with some parameters from the assembly program(from z architecture IBM) . 
The COBOL program  entry point is tnpc001. 
I'm loading the program this way 
 Load  ep=tnpc001

Comment: Are you using the CEEENTRY/CEETERM entry/exit logic macros provided by IBM to LE-enable your Assembler program?

Comment: Is the assembly program LE compliant? Is the COBOL program? And are you in batch? Is the call going to be static or dynamic?

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.ceea400/priasm.htm